# Text transitions to overlap

Tags: jquery, css

I have been trying to get the `h2` element to drop from the `h1` elements final position once it has fully loaded in and stopped its transition. I have not been able to achieve this and currently the `h2` element just fades in from just below the `h1` element.

Here is my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcymtdfb/2/):

```js
$('#header').delay(3250).animate({ 'opacity': [1, "linear"] }, 500);
$('#subheader').delay(4000).animate({ 'opacity': [1, "linear"] }, 500);
```

```css
h1, h2 {
 opacity: 0;
}

/* HEADER TRANSITION */
.moveHeader {
  -webkit-animation: headerMoving 1.5s;
  animation: headerMoving 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes headerMoving {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes headerMoving {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

/* SUBHEADER TRANSITION */
.moveSub {
  -webkit-animation: subMoving 1s;
  animation: subMoving 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes subMoving {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes subMoving {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header" class="moveHeader">Header</h1>
<h2 id="subheader" class="moveSub">Subheader</h2>
```

It takes 3/4 seconds for the animation to begin when pressing run.

Thank you!

Comment: please pay attention when editing question, you transform a code automatically to a snippet and it's a SASS code not CSS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850691/svg-element-rotate-on-circle/55850831#55850831)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? You just needed to change the values of the `translateY` from `-10` to `-50` on the subheader transition. Play with it and see what's suits you best.

Try it out to see if that's what you needed.

```js
$('#header').delay(3250).animate({ 'opacity': [1, "linear"] }, 500);
$('#subheader').delay(4000).animate({ 'opacity': [1, "linear"] }, 500);
```

```css
h1, h2 {
 opacity: 0;
}

/* HEADER TRANSITION */
.moveHeader {
  -webkit-animation: headerMoving 1.5s;
  animation: headerMoving 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes headerMoving {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes headerMoving {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

/* SUBHEADER TRANSITION */
.moveSub {
  -webkit-animation: subMoving 1s;
  animation: subMoving 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes subMoving {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes subMoving {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header" class="moveHeader">Header</h1>
<h2 id="subheader" class="moveSub">Subheader</h2>
```